# How to call a function every time a variable is changed?

Tags: java

I am looking for a way to make a function (e.g. update function) be called every time a certain variable is somehow changed. Either by me or otherwise, as in calls to unknown functions.

Is this possible? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not how imperative programming works

Comment: maybe Observable is what you looking for https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no direct way to do this. But an acceptable solution would be to use a setter:

```
private int a = 1;

public void setA(int a) {
    this.a = a;
    update();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main m = new Main();
    m.setA(2);
}
```

Comment: Don't know who and why downvoted (may be looked for reflection?!). But I upvoted your answer as most useful and complete. So, now you have zero))))

Answer (score 0):

the most flexible way is to use PropertyChangeSupport and writing some thing like this :

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;

public class MyClass {
    private PropertyChangeSupport pptChangeSupport;

    private int field1;
    private int field2;
    private int field3;

    public int getField1() {
        return field1;
    }

    public void setField1(int field1) {
        int oldValue = this.field1;
        this.field1 = field1;
        fireChange("field1", oldValue, field1);
    }

    public int getField2() {
        return field2;
    }

    public void setField2(int field2) {
        int oldValue = this.field2;
        this.field2 = field2;
        fireChange("field2", oldValue, field2);
    }

    public int getField3() {
        return field3;
    }

    public void setField3(int field3) {
        int oldValue = this.field3;
        this.field3 = field3;
        fireChange("field3", oldValue, field3);
    }

    public MyClass() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private void fireChange(String pptName, int oldValue, int newValue) {
        if (pptChangeSupport != null) {
            getPropertyChangeSupport().firePropertyChange(pptName, oldValue, newValue);
        }
    }

    private PropertyChangeSupport getPropertyChangeSupport() {
        return pptChangeSupport == null ? pptChangeSupport = new PropertyChangeSupport(this) : pptChangeSupport;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass object = new MyClass();
        PropertyChangeSupport pptchangesupport = object.getPropertyChangeSupport();
        pptchangesupport.addPropertyChangeListener(e -> System.out
                .println("property " + e.getPropertyName() + " changed : " + e.getOldValue() + " -> " + e.getNewValue()));
        object.setField1((int) (Math.random()*Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        object.setField3((int) (Math.random()*Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        object.setField2((int) (Math.random()*Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        object.setField1((int) (Math.random()*Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        object.setField2((int) (Math.random()*Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        object.setField3((int) (Math.random()*Integer.MAX_VALUE));
        object.setField2((int) (Math.random()*Integer.MAX_VALUE));
    }



}
```

Comment: At the begining I thought that you approach uses reflection and other cool shenanigans... But at the end - you code is identical to @Haytam answer, but with massive boilerplate.

Comment: Functionnaly its the same Things the only differences is that any one can listen to this class and you can easily add other field to your class and handle this with a custom way

Comment: You can  listen to field by only one my way : java agent and jvm instrumentation this is very complicated way and this will slow  down hardly your execution , reflection can t give you that ; reflection is way to analyze or modify class not an object ...

Answer (score -1):

Other than just calling update yourself after setting the variable, you could wrap that up in a function call and ensure that all `a =` usages use `setA` instead

Otherwise, there is no "notification system" for reassignment of a variable

```
private static void setA(int a) { 
    Main.a = a;
    update();
} 

public static void main(String[] args){
    setA(2);
}
```

Outside of this simple example, what you're looking for is called the Observer design pattern